# how to save product grin in customer in magento 2 customer_index_edit.xml

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

How to save product grid in customer tab Add grid in customer_form but I can't save it

Go Through this link

[How to save custom grid check box check data in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145618/how-to-save-custom-grid-check-box-check-data-in-magento-2)

Comment: Hi any have solution then please share with me

Comment: Go through this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147985/how-do-i-add-product-grid-in-customer-admin-section-and-save-the-checbox-values?stw=2

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147985/how-do-i-add-product-grid-in-customer-admin-section-and-save-the-checbox-values?stw=2