# How do i add product grid in customer admin section and save the checkbox values to database

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, custom

I want to add product grid in Magento 2 admin customer section with a separate tab, that I got completed, but when I select the checkbox values from grid and hit save.

It does not get the values of that grid and checkbox values in get and post action.

I have checked multiple time and tried lot with that but it seems like not working.

Any help on this will be appreciated and a knowledge sharing parts for others.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First put block like below code,

**view/adminhtml/layout/Custom.xml**

```
<block class="Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Custom" name="edit.tab.custom"/>
        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Serializer" name="custom_grid_serializer">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="grid_block" xsi:type="string">edit.tab.custom</argument>
                <argument name="callback" xsi:type="string">getSelectedProducts</argument>
                <argument name="input_element_name" xsi:type="string">product_ids</argument>
                <argument name="reload_param_name" xsi:type="string">products_listing</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="grid_scriptjs" template="Company_Module::scriptjs.phtml"/>
```

Add template like below code,

In **view/adminhtml/templates/scriptjs.phtml**

```
<script>
    require([
        "jquery",

    ], function($){     
        $("input[name='product_ids']").attr('data-form-part','customer_form');      
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the module that will add new tab in admin customer and also save selected products to database.

[Add product grid in customer admin section](http://hkpatel201.blogspot.com/2018/10/add-product-grid-in-customer-admin-section.html)